# How to groupby a column and count the number of unique values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe. I need to groupby the ngram, and for each group, count how many unique documents are present in the DocID column.

[image]

For example, from the above

```
4-gram group - 4 as number of unique documents (doc64,doc383,doc76,doc370)
5-gram - 4 
6-gram - 4
7-gram - 2
8-gram - 2
```

I have an idea in bits. I can get the unique DocIDs as follows:

```
#Get all the docs of repeated summaries in one list as a list of lists.
rep = []
rep += temp['DocID'].str.split(",").tolist()

# Put all values in one list.
repSet = []
for i in range(len(rep)):
    repSet.extend(rep[i])

# Remove all duplicates and store in a list.
repSet = list(set(repSet))
```

But I don't know how to merge this with groupby.

**EDIT**

I have added the output from the first answer provided. Thank you! But the total number of documents are only 461. So I believe the maximum value of the DocID can go up to only that much :( but for the trigram its above 461 :(

[image]

Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible example as text and the matching expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
df.assign(docid=df['docid'].str.split(',')).explode('docid').groupby('ngram')['docid'].nunique().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my question to include the output of your answer. I can't figure out how the docid value of trigram is greater than 461. I have only 461 documents in all. So I thought that would be the highest possible I could get. But trigram docid goes to 701. :(

Comment: I made a few modifications and it worked! Thank you so much!